# Is there an opposite to WHERE field IN (:List<Object>)

Tags: java, android, android-room

I want to select all fields from a table where the id does not match with one of the List values. I can find those who match easily but what about in opposite way?

```
@Query("SELECT * table WHERE id IN (:listOfIds)")
List<TableObject> selectOpposite(List<Integer> listOfIds);
```

Comment: `@Query("SELECT * table WHERE id NOT IN (:listOfIds)")`

Comment: that solved the problem thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `NOT IN` instead of `IN`.